# Why can I not import numpy in terminal while being able to import it in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

Today I decided to update my Anaconda distribution. But after the update, when I try to import numpy in the terminal or in VScode, I get the following error message (which I just quote the last lines)

```
import numpy


ImportError:
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

However, it is perfectly fine to import numpy in Jupyter notebook. I wonder what is the origin of my problem and how I can fix this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "I decided to update my Anaconda distribution" exactly?

Comment: Do you have multiple installations of python?

Comment: Sounds like you're either using a different installation of python as @busybear said or using a virtual environment with a different version of numpy

Comment: The strange thing is that I actually have only one version of python and I make sure that all the rest is deleted. The way to prove it I think is to type "where python" in terminal and also run sys.executable in notebook, they point to the same python.exe file.

Comment: What is `sys.path` in both the terminal and the notebook?  They may be finding different versions of numpy.

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda comes with its own Numpy and that is why you can access it in Jupyter.You will have to find the correct install file for you version of Python. You should be able to see this when you open your terminal.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but the strange thing is that I actually have only one version of python and I make sure that all the rest is deleted. The way to prove it I think is to type "where python" in terminal and also run sys.executable in notebook, they point to the same python.exe file.

Comment: in your shell look for something like this and use this when searching for the correct Wheel EX([MSC v.1915 32 bit (Intel)] on win32)